# Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 myTODO Error message

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I have downloaded the [myTODO](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mytodo/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3093) Azure sample application and when trying to run it locally I am receiving the following very puzzling error message.

```
The item "..\MyTodo.WebUx\MyTodo.WebUx.csproj" in item list 
"ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration" does not define a value for metadata "Configuration".  
In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration.Configuration), 
or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata. 
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Cloud Service\1.0\Visual Studio 10.0\Microsoft.CloudService.targets
```

Below is an extractfrom the MyToDo.WebUX.csproj file, what do I change?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
<ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the web project to convert, remove the following from the  element: "{603c0e0b-db56-11dc-be95-000d561079b0};"

That sample is out of date though ... you can use it to look at the tests project, but to get a more up to date vs2008 version of the majority of that project's code, try downloading the source to this lab: [DeployingApplicationsinWindowsAzure](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Azure/Deployment/DeployingApplicationsinWindowsAzure/).

The Source link is in the upper right corner.  If you look at the end folder for the 3 exercise you will find a more up to date version of this project ... however I don't think the complete solution is there so you'll have to compare it to the one you linked to above.

... I haven't compared the projects myself so I don't know what is missing between the lab version and the one on code gallery.

Comment: Thanks, project converts now but receiving AppDomainUnloadedException.

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue today where MSBuild was giving me an almost identical error:

```
The item "xxx.csproj" in item list "ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration" does not define a value for metadata "Name".
```

Fortunately, I had another Azure service that was compiling correctly, so I was able to search out the differences. It turned out that in the solution that was working, `MyService.ccproj` (the Azure Service project) was compiling *before* `xxx.csproj`. In the solution that was failing, `xxx.csproj` was compiling first. When I specified the dependencies such that `xxx.csproj` compiled after `MyService.ccproj`, it started working.

I'm not sure exactly what's going on here, or what it is about `xxx.csproj` that makes it so it has to come after. If I figure it out I'll update, but maybe this will help you.

UPDATE: It seems like maybe Azure does not like it if you specify anything besides an Azure Role project as a dependency on the service project. I made it so `MyWebRole.csproj` was dependent on `xxx.csproj`, instead of `MyService.ccproj` being dependent on `xxx.csproj`, and it worked.