# Azure Project build package working from VS, failing from command line with error MSB4096

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have a solution with a Windows Azure Cloud Services project, that compiles fine from VS and command line.

If I try to make a package, it works fine from VS, but fails from command line.

Here is my command line from Powershell:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe .\project.sln --% 
/p:Configuration="QA" /p:TargetProfile="CloudQA" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /target:Publish
/nr:false
```

I have this error:

```
"C:\CI\project\project.sln" (Publish target) (1) ->
"C:\CI\project\WindowsAzure\WindowsAzure.ccproj.metaproj" (Publish target) (11) ->
"C:\CI\project\WindowsAzure\WindowsAzure.ccproj" (Publish target) (12) ->
(PrepareRoleItems target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.0\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(13
02,5): error MSB4096: The item "C:\CI\project\project.WebAPI\project.WebAPI.csproj" in item list "Projec
tReferenceWithConfiguration" does not define a value for metadata "Name".  In order to use this metadata, either qualif
y it by specifying %(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration.Name), or ensure that all items in this list define a value for
this metadata. [C:\CI\project\WindowsAzure\WindowsAzure.ccproj]
```

**EDIT**
Few interesting things:
Here is my csdef file

```
<WorkerRole name="ProjectWorker" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
  <Imports>
    <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
  </Imports>
  <Endpoints>
    <InternalEndpoint name="InternalEndpoint1" protocol="http" />
  </Endpoints>
  <ConfigurationSettings>
  </ConfigurationSettings>
</WorkerRole>
<WebRole name="Project.Web" vmsize="ExtraSmall">
  <Sites>
    <Site name="Web">
      <Bindings>
        <Binding name="http" endpointName="http" />
      </Bindings>
    </Site>
    <Site name="Api" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\Project.WebAPI">
      <Bindings>
        <Binding name="http" endpointName="http81" />
      </Bindings>
    </Site>
  </Sites>
  <Endpoints>
    <InputEndpoint name="http" protocol="http" port="80" />
    <InputEndpoint name="http81" protocol="http" port="81" />
  </Endpoints>
  <Imports>
    <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
  </Imports>
</WebRole>
```

As you can see, I have two websites on one WebRole.

Now, let's have a look at the ccproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Project.Web\Project.Web.csproj">
    <Name>Project.Web</Name>
    <Project>{5d000123-0000-4b6e-b5fa-72525afca7f5}</Project>
    <Private>True</Private>
    <RoleType>Web</RoleType>
    <RoleName>Project.Web</RoleName>
    <UpdateDiagnosticsConnectionStringOnPublish>True</UpdateDiagnosticsConnectionStringOnPublish>
  </ProjectReference>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectWorker\ProjectWorker.csproj">
    <Name>ProjectWorker</Name>
    <Project>{22e99999-1000-4559-8507-a948b7e3d1b0}</Project>
    <Private>True</Private>
    <RoleType>Worker</RoleType>
    <RoleName>ProjectWorker</RoleName>
    <UpdateDiagnosticsConnectionStringOnPublish>True</UpdateDiagnosticsConnectionStringOnPublish>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Only two projects are referenced in the ccproj instead of 3.

The cloud project has 3 dependencies in the sln.

If I had a reference by hand in the ccproj like this:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Project.WebAPI\Project.WebAPI.csproj">
  <Name>Project.Web</Name>
  <Project>{A0F88888-3333-4823-A34F-5F01F0A3FFFF}</Project>
  <Private>True</Private>
  <RoleType>Web</RoleType>
  <RoleName>Project.WebAPI</RoleName>
  <UpdateDiagnosticsConnectionStringOnPublish>True</UpdateDiagnosticsConnectionStringOnPublish>
</ProjectReference>
```

I have this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.0
\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(987,5): error : CloudServices25 : Multiple directories are 
specified for role Project.Web. [C:\CI\project\WindowsAzure\WindowsAzure.ccproj]
```

Now if I update the reference like this:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Project.WebAPI\Project.WebAPI.csproj">
  <Name>Project.WebAPI</Name>
  <Project>{A0F88888-3333-4823-A34F-5F01F0A3FFFF}</Project>
  <Private>True</Private>
  <RoleType>Web</RoleType>
  <RoleName>Project.Web</RoleName>
  <UpdateDiagnosticsConnectionStringOnPublish>True</UpdateDiagnosticsConnectionStringOnPublish>
</ProjectReference>
```

I have this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.0
\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(987,5): error : CloudServices26 : Cannot find role 
named 'Project.WebAPI' in service description file 
C:\CI\project\WindowsAzure\bin\UAT\ServiceDefinition.csdef.     
[C:\CI\project\WindowsAzure\WindowsAzure.ccproj]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post solved my problem:
http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/multiple-sites-in-a-web-role/

A must read if you have several websites on one webrole!

Answer (score 6):

I found this link: [Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 myTODO Error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012609/visual-studio-2010-beta-2-mytodo-error-message) it works for me. The valuable information from that link:

> It seems like maybe Azure does not like it if you specify anything besides an Azure Role project as a dependency on the service project. I made it so MyWebRole.csproj was dependent on xxx.csproj, instead of MyService.ccproj being dependent on xxx.csproj, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon a similar problem when building my cloud project from the command line, in particular I get this exception if the web project referenced by the `VirtualDirectory` tag is marked as a build dependency for the cloud project.

To avoid this and ensure that the web project is compiled and included in the `cspack`, I come up with a procedure simpler that the one cited in [Swell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17065997/753737) -- in particular it does not require to alter the project files but only to call two targets in a precise order:

1. ensure in `Configuration Manager` that the web project will be rebuilt in the desired solution configuration (for example ensure that it is built under `Release` configuration);
2. ensure that the web project is not a build dependency of the cloud project;
3. do a rebuild of the solution, for example

   ```
   MsBuild solution.sln /t:Rebuild ...
   ```

   This way the web project will be recompiled.
4. perform a publish of the cloud project, for example

   ```
   MsBuild solution.sln /t:cloudproject.ccproj:publish ...
   ```

   The web project will be copied correctly to the `cspack` file.